# Tracking feature if recipients read an email (engineering question)

Tags: algorithm, architecture, feature-engineering

I am study computer science and have a final project at the university on the subject of emails and clients.
The project we are working on is to create a dashboard that allows the user to send an email through us and receive indications of the email - viewing the email, displaying the responses to the email from recipients and more..

**One of the features we need to support is knowing who has read the email to the user**. When it comes to sending an email to one recipient we were able to solve it relatively easily according to what we found on the internet - we planted a 1x1 pixel that makes an api call to our server and reports that the email was read and it worked!
**We need to support this feature even when the user sends an email to 4 different recipients. To know which of the recipients read the email.**
We saw on the Internet that this feature exists in many products, but we could not figure out how to implement it.
Any idea or direction how to achieve this?

I have searched online for solutions and reviewed many products to see this is possible.

Comment: You can make `N` distinct emails with a distinct API call each, and then send each to one of the `N` recipients, but still listing the other `N-1` addresses in the `TO` header. To them, it'll look like it was sent to everyone.  Note that after someone replies all to it, the others will receive that person's copy, meaning they'll also make that API call (but guaranteed to be after the original target). This may cause some weird behavior in email clients that collapse email chains, since the email reply will be to a different email than the one they received.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What do you mean by still listing the other N-1 addresses in the TO header?
Each recipient will get N emails? because I want him to get only 1 at the end

Comment: No, the "TO" header literally just lists who else this email was allegedly sent to. It serves no functional role in delivering the emails- its essentially there to look pretty. What actually dictates who (as in, ONE individual address) the email is sent to is carried in the message envelope, which you can customize per-target.

Comment: Thanks @DillonDavis! I will take a try

Comment: The play with the 'TO' header worked, but as you said, when someone is replying to that mail, it will shown as another email in the other recipients (they will see twice the same email..).
Is there any way to overcome this?
How email chrome extension products are achieving this behavior? they know to supply the ability to reply to multi-participant email and each recipient has one context

Comment: I believe that you can trick the clients into believing its the same message. Many of them seemingly use the "In-Reply-To" and "References" headers to group emails, which themselves contain the "Message-ID" header of the original email. This "Message-ID" is intended to be unique per email, and is probably being auto-generated for you, but if you manually supply and reuse one, it may trick the clients into thinking its the same email.  The "Message-ID" is supposed to look like "<UNIQUE_IDENT@HOST>"

Comment: You are suggesting that i will create a unique message-id and use it in all the N emails i am sending (with unique pixel in each one)?

Comment: I'm suggesting that that could work to solve the email chain/collapsing issue